# Static vs Dynamic arrays in cudaMalloc()

Tags: cuda

Are there any differences w.r.t `cudaMalloc(...)` and `cudaMemCpy(...)` amongst the following two approaches:

```
#1. Use dynamic host arrays:

float *a_host_1 = new float [10]();
float *a_dyn;
...
cudaMalloc((void **) &a_dyn, 10);
...
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) a_host_1[i] = (float)i*2;
cudaMemcpy(a_dyn, a_host_1, 10, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

#2. Use static host arrays:

float a_host_2[] = {1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0};
float *a_st;
...
cudaMalloc((void **) &a_st, 10);
...
cudaMemcpy(a_st, a_host_2, 10, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Regards,
Sayan

Comment: When I try to time the cudaMalloc for both the cases, there are differences in timing, so I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@aaa is spot on, the only difference is that the first approach will take a few more flops to run through the loop than option 2 (negligible). However by the time the code reaches the `cudaMemcpy` `a_host_1` and `a_host_2` are identical.

Defining `a_host_2` as `const` might make a difference but any timing differences you're seeing aren't down to the dynamic/static declarations.